# How to replace btrfs root subvolume with received snapshot?

Tags: backup, btrfs, restore

I want to convert my existing full-disk btrfs (unpartitioned) filesystems to bcache.
To do so, I need to move data around and reformat the drives.
I have enough hdd space to do it in a couple steps.

Since I'm using btrfs, I thought `btrfs send` and `btrfs receive` would make this easy.

I have created a readonly snapshot of the fs I want to convert first and started sending it into a subvolume in another fs.

What I'm unclear about is how I would go about restoring that duplicated subvolume to the original disk once my superblock conversions have taken place.

The `btrfs receive` manpage indicates that it can only create new subvolumes and it also makes them readonly once the process is complete.

So how do I replace a fresh writable root subvolume from a received snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever I received will be a new readonly subvolume, that's just how Btrfs works. And as Emmanuel hinted in the other answer, there might not be a clean and intuitive way to do it differently.

Here are steps to make the received subvolume behave as the root volume:

```bash
cd /mnt/drv/receivedvolume
btrfs property set -ts . ro false # make it writeable
btrfs subvolume list . # take note of the ID of the volume, i'll use 123 here
btrfs subvolume set-default 123 /mnt/drv
```

Additionally, for added peace of mind, it's possible to add the `subvolid=123` mount option to `/etc/fstab` or any other mounting jobs.

If this is actually going to be the / of a system, it might be necessary to reinstall the bootloader

Answer (score 2):

> So how do I replace a fresh writable root subvolume from a received
>   snapshot?

You can't.

In your case the top-level (root) subvolume (which is ID 5) is the `/` of your Linux filesystem; Nothing can exist adjacent to it. As you discovered, `btrfs-receive` creates a read-only subvolume, so what you'd have to do is create a read-write snapshot subvolume from the read-only one, and for that you'd need to be able to create a subvolume outside of `/`; Hence why you can't replace the top-level subvolume.

Notice that you said:

> I have created a readonly snapshot of the **fs** I want to convert first
>   and started sending it into a **subvolume** in another fs.

What you did though, is create a read-only snapshot of a **subvolume**, not the BTRFS filesystem as a whole. I don't see how you'd be able to create a snapshot of the top-level though. Weird.

Your best bet is to use a tool like `partclone` to backup the entire filesystem and then restore from that. Otherwise, you'd have to change your subvolume [layout](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Layout) from *flat*, which is what you have, to *nested*. With a nested layout you'd have something like this:

```
/ (top-level)
|
|__ /rootfs (subvolume)
|   |
|   _/home
|
|__ /rootfs-backup (read-only subvolume, which you can delete later)
|   |
|   _/home
```

A nested layout gives you the ability to create snapshots of any subvolume in the filesystem (except the top-level, which you wouldn't need to do anyway). Then you'd simply mount the `rootfs` subvolume on `/`, instead of the entire filesystem. For example: `mount -t btrfs /dev/sda1 -o defaults,subvol=/rootfs`

Comment: Perhaps my wording was bad, by "root" I didn't mean `/` specifically, but rather the toplevel volume of a btrfs filesystem. I've now solved the problem by receiving the volume back onto the bcache-reformatted drive, setting it ro=false, and finally adding the mount option `subvolid=` to point to the received subvolume. This isn't as neat as I would've liked but it works.